# Слово "размолненное" - возможно ли?

Tags: словообразование

Размолненное - прил., означающее разделённое молнией на части. Пример: "вблизи размолненного дерева". Возможно ли применение такого слова? Не противоречит ли каким-либо правилам? Быть может, у него уже существуют синонимы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правилам словообразования не противоречит, но это будет окказионализм - авторский неологизм. В этом Вас немного опередил Ф. Клюев:

Я счастлив, что люди простые

меня поддержали в пути,

что чувство высокой России,

как песня, зарделось в груди,

.............................

что в штурманской, перед полётом,

под песнь застеклённой пурги

в размолненных куртках пилоты

читали мои стихи.

Правда, здесь используется приставка РАЗ- в омонимичном значении "высшая степень какого-либо качества - развесёлый, разудалый" - весь покрытый молниями. Что ж , Вы будете автором окказионализма со значением приставки РАЗ- "деление на части"-разбитое молнией.

Answer (score 2):

В русской грамматике формант РАЗ...И (образование глаголов от существительных и прилагательных) используется  в нескольких случаях:

1) Значение разделить/измельчить, превратив в то, что названо существительным: распылить, расщепить.

2) Наделение признаком, названным прилагательным: разредить, разъяснить, расширить. Приведение в состояние, названное существительным: раззадорить, разохотить, разъярить.

3) Лишить признака: разобщить, рассекретить.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Итак, разобщить – лишить признака,  разъяснить – наделить признаком. Откуда такое противоречие? Можно предположить, что причина заключается в сложном форманте. Приставка РАЗ имеет значение разделения на части, разрушения признака, а суффикс И – значение придания признака. На таком фоне образование новых слов  связано с дополниельными трудностями для понимания их значения.

Образование  по схеме «молния - размолнить»  только на первый взгляд похоже на «пыль – распылить». В действительности мы здесь имеем «расщепить дерево с помощью молнии».

Дополнение:

Размолненная куртка - здесь неологизм не противоречит общей схеме "наделения признаком" и поэтому возможен. "Размолнить дерево" в существующие схемы словообразования не вписывается.

Comment: А если мы подойдём к вопросу по следующей аналогии: "рубка - разрубленный", "укус - раскушенный", "молния - размолененный". Насколько я знаю, ни "разрубленный", ни "раскушеннный" не наделяет признаком (не делает укусом, не делает рубкой) и не соответствует ни одному из трёх приведённых примеров употребления. Поправьте, если я не прав, что слово "размолненный" употребимо по аналогии "укус - раскусить - раскушенное", "молния - (гипотетическое) молнить (в значении бить молнией) - размолненное".

Comment: Существует схема: пила - пилить - распилить, суффикс И обозначает действие, осуществленное с помощью предмета. Поэтому возможно: молния - (молнить) - размолнить.

Answer (score 1):

Нет же такого слова. Вас просто не поймут.

Comment: И  нет  острой  необходимости  в  новом  слове,  если  обычное  выражение - разбитый  молнией -  наделено  тем  же  самым  смыслом.

Comment: Единственное оправдание такому слову - желание выпендриться при написании стихов. Поэтам в словотворчестве раздолье...